# Apache POI PPT (Java) - Removing chart object from PPT

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am updating a PPT template where some placeholder has been organized to receive new dynamic values.

Some of the chart may receive incomplete values and thus I would like to completely delete them from the slide.

In order to match each chart and update it I use XSLFChart object. So I loop over every chart and I update those successfully identifying every chart using the title -> key for the new values.

I have not been able to find a function to delete the placeholder chart if I decide so.

My code would be similar to the one below.

Thanks for any advice.

PS I found this post [Removing chart from PowerPoint slide with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347444/removing-chart-from-powerpoint-slide-with-apache-poi)

but could not link XSLFChart  to XSLFGraphicFrame so I have not been able to exploit this suggestion.

```
    List<XSLFSlide> allSlides = ppt.getSlides();
    int updatedElements = 0;
    for (XSLFSlide currentSlide : allSlides) {
        for (POIXMLDocumentPart part : currentSlide.getRelations()) {
            if (part instanceof XSLFChart) {
                XSLFChart chart = (XSLFChart) part;
                if (SOMETHING_TRUE){
                chart.remove() <-- ANYTHING LIKE THIS?
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My code in the linked SO answer does looping over all shapes in the slide and if the shape instanceof `XSLFGraphicFrame` and does containing a chart, then it adds this to `Map<String, XSLFGraphicFrame> chartFramesToRemove`. So do this adding only `if (SOMETHING_TRUE)`. I don't believe there is a way directly from the `XSLFChart` to the `XSLFGraphicFrame` since the `XSLFGraphicFrame` links to the `XSLFChart` via `rId` but not the other way around.

Comment: My problem is that the condition `if (SOMEHTING_TRUE)` in reality will be part of a try-catch. So, I try to update the chart and if this fail (based on input data), I want to delete the chart (catch option). So I would find an easy -smart way to use your solution.

May I build a map getting all chart shape `{XSLFChart, XSLFGraphicFrame }` via `rId`? - in this way I could create a list of XSLFChart to be deleted and then loop the map get the connected  `XSLFGraphicFrame ` and apply yor code. Does it seem feasible?

Comment: Yes, my code already shows how to get the `XSLFChart` from the `rid`:  `XSLFChart chart = (XSLFChart)slide.getRelationById(rid);`. So just try it.