# Apache POI: Remove Chart from Word Template file entirely

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using a Word template with Excel graphs which I want to programmatically manipulate with the Java Apache POI library. For this I also need to be able to conditionally delete a Chart which is stored in this template.

Based on Axel Richters post ([Removing chart from PowerPoint slide with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347444/removing-chart-from-powerpoint-slide-with-apache-poi?rq=1)) I think I am almost there, but when I want to open the updated Word file it gives an error about unreadable content. This is what I have thus far:

```
PackagePart packagePartChart = xWPFChart.getPackagePart();

PackagePart packagePartWordDoc = xWPFDocument.getPackagePart();
OPCPackage packageWordDoc = packagePartWordDoc.getPackage();

// iterate over all relations the chart has and remove them
for (PackageRelationship chartrelship : packagePartChart.getRelationships()) {
    String partname = chartrelship.getTargetURI().toString();
    PackagePart part = packageWordDoc.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile(partname)).get(0);
    packageWordDoc.removePart(part);
    packagePartChart.removeRelationship(chartrelship.getId());
}

// now remove the chart itself from the word doc                           
Method removeRelation = POIXMLDocumentPart.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeRelation", POIXMLDocumentPart.class); 
removeRelation.setAccessible(true); 
removeRelation.invoke(xWPFDocument, xWPFChart);
```

If I unzip the Word file I correctly see that:

1. the relation between the WordDoc and the Chart are deleted in '\word\ _rels\document.xml.rels'
2. the chart itself is deleted in folder '\word\charts'
3. the relations between the documents supporting the Chart itself are deleted in folder '\word\charts\' _rels
4. the related chart items themselves are deleted:

   - StyleN / ColorsN in folder '\word\charts' and
   - Microsoft_Excel_WorksheetN in folder '\word\embeddings'

Anybody any idea on what could be going wrong here?

Comment: You are not removing the paragraph containing the drawing which refers to the chart in `word/document.xml`. In my PowerPoint example this is `slide.removeShape(chartFrame);`. For Word this can be done using [XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#removeBodyElement-int-). The challenge is to find the position of the paragraph containing the drawing which refers to the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback again Axel. I will be looking into it and will share the result once fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the finding of the right paragraph holding the chart was a challenge. In the end, for simplicity sake, I added a one row/one column placeholder table with one cell with a text, let's say 'targetWordString' in it, DIRECTLY before the chart. With the below function I am location the BodyElementID of this table:

```
private Integer iBodyElementIterator (XWPFDocument wordDoc,String targetWordString) {
    Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = wordDoc.getBodyElementsIterator();
    Integer bodyElementID = null;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
       IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
       bodyElementID = wordDoc.getBodyElements().indexOf(elem);
       if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph) {

           XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) elem;
           for (XWPFRun runText : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                String text = runText.getText(0);                               
               Core.getLogger("WordExporter").trace("Body Element ID:  " + bodyElementID + " Text: " + text);
                if (text != null && text.equals(targetWordString)) {                        
                    break;                          
                }
            }

       } else if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {
           if (((XWPFTable) elem).getRow(0) != null && ((XWPFTable) elem).getRow(0).getCell(0) != null) {
                // the first cell holds the name via the template
                String tableTitle = ((XWPFTable) elem).getRow(0).getCell(0).getText();
                if (tableTitle.equals(targetWordString)) {
                    break;
                }
                Core.getLogger("WordExporter").trace("Body Element ID:  " + bodyElementID + " Text: " + tableTitle);
           } else {
               Core.getLogger("WordExporter").trace("Body Element ID:  " + bodyElementID + " Table removed!");
           }

       }
       else {
           Core.getLogger("WordExporter").trace("Body Element ID:  " + bodyElementID + " Text: ?");
       }
    }
    return bodyElementID;
}
```

In the main part of the code I am calling this function to locate the table, then first delete the chart (ID +1) and then the table (ID)

```
int elementIDToBeRemoved = iBodyElementIterator(xWPFWordDoc,targetWordString);

xWPFWordDoc.removeBodyElement(elementIDToBeRemoved + 1);
xWPFWordDoc.removeBodyElement(elementIDToBeRemoved);
```

It needs to be in this order, because the ID's are reordered once you delete a number in between, hence deleting the table first, would mean the chart would get that ID in principle.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a more structural solution for it without the use of dummy tables for the positioning. The solution is build out into 2 parts:

1. Determine relationship id of chart in word document
2. Remove chart based on relationship id and remove paragraph + runs

**Determine relationship id of chart in word document**

First I have determined with a boolean variable 'chartUsed' whether the chart needs to be deleted.

```
       if (!chartUsed) {
            String chartPartName = xWPFChart.getPackagePart().getPartName().getName();
            String ridChartToBeRemoved = null;
            
            // iterate over all relations the chart has and remove them
            for (RelationPart relation : wordDoc.getRelationParts()) {
                PackageRelationship relShip = relation.getRelationship();
                if (relShip.getTargetURI().toString().equals(chartPartName)) {
                    ridChartToBeRemoved = relShip.getId();
                    Core.getLogger(logNode).info("Chart with title " + chartTitle + " has relationship id " + relShip.getId());
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            removeChartByRelId(wordDoc, ridChartToBeRemoved);
            
        }
```

(Core.getLogger is an internal API from the Mendix low code platform I use).

At the end I am calling the function removeChartByRelId which will remove the chart if the relation is found within a run of a paragraph:

**Remove chart based on relationship id and remove paragraph + runs**

```
    private void removeChartByRelId (XWPFDocument wordDoc, String chartRelId) {
        Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = wordDoc.getBodyElementsIterator();
        Integer bodyElementID = null;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
           IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
           bodyElementID = wordDoc.getBodyElements().indexOf(elem);
           if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
               Core.getLogger(logNode).trace("XWPFParagraph Body Element ID:  " + bodyElementID);
               
               XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) elem;
               boolean removeParagraph = false;
               for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                    if (run.getCTR().getDrawingList().size()>0) {
                        String drawingXMLText = run.getCTR().getDrawingList().get(0).xmlText();
                        boolean isChart = drawingXMLText.contains("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
                        String graphicDataXMLText = run.getCTR().getDrawingList().get(0).getInlineArray(0).getGraphic().getGraphicData().xmlText();                 
                        boolean contains = graphicDataXMLText.contains(chartRelId);
                        if (isChart && contains) {
                            Core.getLogger(logNode).info("Removing chart with relId " + chartRelId + " as it isnt used in data");
                            run.getCTR().getDrawingList().clear();
                            removeParagraph = true;
                        }                       
                    }
                }
               if (removeParagraph) {
                   for (int i = 0; i < paragraph.getRuns().size(); i++){
                      paragraph.removeRun(i);
                   }
               }
            } 
        }
}
```